# Convergence of a series, how to prove convergence using comparision

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I find out if this sum converges or diverges?

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan(n^{-7/3}) $$

Wolfram tells me to use the comparison test but I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For $x\ge 0$ you have the inequality $\tan^{-1}x\le x$.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch:

1. $x \leq \tan(x)$ for $0 \leq x < \pi/2$.
2. $\tan$ is a strict monotone increasing function (ergo bijective) in the above interval.
3. $\frac{1}{n^{7/3}} < \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

QED

Answer (score 1):

Since ArcTan[x] < x for 0 < x < 1, then the sum has an upper bound which is Zeta[7/3], Zeta being the Riemann Zeta function. The numerical value of Zeta[7/3] = 1.41516.

If we expand ArcTan[x] as a Taylor series around x = 0 and then replace x by k^(-7/3), the infinite summation results in a linear combination of Zeta functions the limit of which being close to 1.19783.

Answer (score 0):

By using the equivalence $\tan^{-1}{x}\underset{x\to{0}}{\sim}{x}$ and the fact that $n^{-\frac{7}{3}}\underset{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow}{0},$ we can conclude that
$$\tan^{-1}{n^{-\frac{7}{3}}}\underset{n\to\infty}{\sim}{n^{-\frac{7}{3}}}.$$